# How can i code the Title of a UIButton to change across two View Controllers?

Tags: swift, uibutton, segue, viewcontroller, swift5

This is what i have but it does not work. I want the bbutton on vc3 to change title depending on what image is displayed on VC2

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if imageDisplayed == UIImage(named: "sad") && segue.identifier == "goToActive"{
        let vc3 = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
            vc3.buttonTitle.titleLabel?.text = "no"
    }
else if imageDisplayed == UIImage(named: "happy") && segue.identifier == "goToActive" {
let vc3 = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
    vc3.buttonTitle.titleLabel?.text = "happy"


} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create a property named `text` in your `ThirdViewController` and set it as `buttonTitle's` `title` in `viewDidLoad()` like so,

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTitle: UIButton!
    var text: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.buttonTitle.setTitle(self.text, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

This is because, the *IBOutlet* won't be set until `viewDidLoad()` is called. So, accessing the `button` in `vc2` will result in runtime exception.

Next, your `SecondViewController` should look like,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc3 = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {
            var buttonTitle: String?
            switch self.imageView.image {
            case UIImage(named: "sad"): buttonTitle = "no"
            case UIImage(named: "happy"): buttonTitle = "happy"
            default: break
            }
            vc3.text = buttonTitle
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. In `prepare(for:sender:)`, set the `text` of `vc3` as per the `imageView's` `image`.
2. There is no need to create `buttonPressed(_:)` `IBAction`. All that will be handled in `prepare(for:sender:)` itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the IBAction call the performSegue

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToActive", sender: nil)  
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if imageDisplayed == UIImage(named: "sad") && segue.identifier == "goToActive"{
        let vc3 = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
        vc3.buttonTitle.("no", for: .normal)
    }
    else if imageDisplayed == UIImage(named: "happy") && segue.identifier == "goToActive" {
        let vc3 = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
        vc3.buttonTitle.("happy", for: .normal)
    }
}
```